# Fundamental Neighborhood in Ordinary Differential Equations

Tags: general-topology, geometry, ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, dynamical-systems

Consider the ODE
\begin{align}
\dot x = f(x) \tag{1}
\end{align}
Let $x_0$ be a hyperbolic fixed point of $(1)$. Let $V$ be a neighborhood of $x_0$ in $W^s(x_0)$, where $W^s(x_0)$ is the stable manifold of $x_0$. 
First of all, if the boundary of $V$, i.e., $\partial V$ is transversal to the vector field $f$, then $\partial V$ is a fundamental domain of $W^s(x_0)$. The intuition behind the *fundamental domain* has been clarified [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2955454/567412).

In this question, I am thinking about another interesting concept, namely *fundamental neighborhood* which is tightly related to fundamental domain.
By definition, any cross section of the vector field $f$ containing $\partial V$ and transversal to $W^s(x)$ is called the fundamental neighborhood $G(x)$ associated with $W^s(x)$.

Based on the concept of fundamental domain and fundamental neighborhood, we have the following results:

1. $W^s(x) = \cup_{t\in \mathbb{R}} \phi_t(\partial V) \cup {x}$,
2. $\cup_{t\ge 0} \phi_t(G(x)) \cup W^u(x)$ contains a neighborhood of
   $x$.

I saw the above results and definitions in [Hirsch's paper](https://doi.org/10.1109/9.357) (page 3, above Theorem 3-3), but there is no reference or clarification in the paper.

I greatly appreciate it if someone can clarify or provide a reference for the concept of fundamental neighborhood or the results 1 and 2.

Thank you!

Comment: You asked the same thing a few days ago. Any new thoughts of yours?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2955454/fundamental-domain-and-transversality-of-vector-field-in-ordinary-differential-e

Comment: This is a follow-up on my previous question. I will edit the question to show the differences. I will add my thoughts soon.

Comment: Just draw a picture. Notice that the fixed point does not evolve and so it needs to be added separately. Other than this the only reasonable comment is that the notion is neither standard/canonical nor necessary. Presumably you have encountered it in something related to Conley index or similar. But you really should tell us where you have encountered it, really you should not expect someone to disclose their thoughts if you don't disclose anything.

Comment: @JohnB . Thanks for the comment. I revised the question. I do not have a strong background in topology or geometry. I saw this concept in a paper (mentioned above) without providing any reference and I thought this might be a well-known result in topology or geometry.